# Merging lines - based on condition

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a table of lines containing geometry, name and color.There are few types of these lines. First one has different geometries and same name and color. These types should be merged into one segment.

```
geometry| name   | color
A1      |Szlak 1 |blue
A2      |Szlak 1 |blue
```

Result:

```
geometry| name   | color
A1+A2   |Szlak 1 |blue
```

Above case is already solved with this code:

```
WITH singleRow as ( 
   select count(way), way
   from planet_osm_line 
   group by way
   having count(way) > 1
)
SELECT P.*
FROM planet_osm_line P
JOIN singleRow S
  ON P.way = S.way
```

Second type is when 2 lines have the same geometry but different names or color.

```
geometry| name   | color
A1      |Szlak 1 |blue
A1      |Szlak 2 |green
```

In this case I need a result like this (all tags in one row):

```
geometry| name   | color | name1   |color1
A1      |Szlak 1 |blue   |Szlak 2  |green
```

If 2 lines have same geometry but have different name and color I need them to be in one row, name1,name2 etc.

Thank you.

Comment: why you dont get `1+2+3+4, A, Blue` ?? what is the join condition? I think you should improve your picture, to me isnt clear what you mean by `overlaping`. If one street is over another one you can show that putting a very wide line in one color and the other road over with a different color and small width. Otherwise looks like two different road side by side.

Comment: I think you need add a field more to your table something like `segmentID` or `GeomID`. In the picture I can see `1A = 3C` but in the table I **cant**. Also I think would need more sample cases. Like what happenf if `B = Green`

Comment: I know some have same geometry, can you simulate that field with GeomID?

Comment: Learn how make a good question, I try to explain it but you dont seem to understand.  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry, I created my question from scratch. Sorry for being such a noob :) Thank you.

Comment: `when 2 lines have the same geometry`  where is the geometry on your sample? `way` mean geometry?. Take your time and read the question to yourself and think if make sense for someone who doesnt know your problem..

Comment: yes, way is geometry. I corrected this one as well.

Comment: Ok, You realize those need to be two different querys? Because one will merge geometry and return `color, name`, The other will remove duplicate geometry and return multiple `colors, name`. Also, what happen if 3 or 4 geometry are the same? or only 2 is possible.

Comment: I suppose I need separate query for each one but I can merge the results s later into one big table.

Comment: You say you already solve first case. This is the solution for second case you need? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/037bc/1 ... Feel free to update the SqlFiddle with more data if want make the example more descriptive

Comment: wow! you are the man! Almost there, is it possible to split string_agg into separate columns? string_agg1 for first name and string_agg2 for second name?

Comment: Is possible only if you have only have two rows with same geometry. Didnt you read my question? `Also, what happen if 3 or 4 geometry are the same? or only 2 is possible.` but for that you need a column `geometryID` otherwise you may combine same links to itself

Comment: Yes, I read your question. Most possible duplicating lines (same geometry but different name and color) is 6. What do you mean by geometryID? How should I add it?

Comment: Sorry, I give up on you. You **CANT** have a query returning 2, 4, 6 column at same time. Is like try to get apples from a banana tree.

Comment: The only thing I need at the moment is to create a query for 2. I will do the other one. The only thing that is missing in your fiddle is to put 2 different names in separate columns, not separated by comma. Please just show me how to this one...

Comment: I told you, You need one `ID` column to be PK on your table.